# How to insert a in-cell dropdown list button?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is there a way to insert into a spreadsheet cell a "Display in-cell button to show list" through Apps Script, ie, insert a dropdown list as we can do (without programming) using `Data>>Data Validation` spreadsheet menu?
I need the dropdown list to be shown in the cell (and not in a Uiapp).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to review the methods offered here - https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-validation-builder

Answer (score 8):

I think that the answer to my question is here:

```
 // Set the data validation for cell A1 to require "Yes" or "No", with no dropdown menu.
 var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('A1');
 var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(['Yes', 'No'], false).build();
 cell.setDataValidation(rule);
```

Comment: Hi there! This works for me but the only thing I notice is that it visually doesn't show the dropdown arrow. Have you figured out how to do that?

Comment: @p0tta yes, to show the dropdown arrow in the cell, you should set the `showDropdown` parameter to `true`. In the example, this parameter is set to `false`.

Comment: This works really nicely - just what I wanted!  I did find I needed to update my appscript.json file to include "oauthScopes": [ "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets" ] and then grant authorization for my Google account (had to respond to some popup dialogs generated by Google).

Comment: Hey folks remember to upvote the original Question when you get value from the Question and Answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is a response to [p0tta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/544982/p0tta)'s question:

> This works for me but the only thing I notice is that it visually doesn't show the dropdown arrow. Have you figured out how to do that?

If you check the rules for:

> requireValueInList(values, showDropdown)

of Google's [Class DataValidationBuilder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-validation-builder), you will see that [craftApprentice](https://stackoverflow.com/users/955883/craftapprentice) put it as `false` in their sample code.

You will want to put it as `true`:

```
// Set the data validation for cell A1 to require "Yes" or "No", with no dropdown menu.
var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('A1');
var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(['Yes', 'No'], true).build();
cell.setDataValidation(rule);
```

Hope this clarifies!
Also, thanks [craftApprentice](https://stackoverflow.com/users/955883/craftapprentice) for answering this question so simply.